# How to get implement Scatter charts in Android using AndroidPlot ? is it possible to get clieck event of the point in chart?

Tags: charts, androidplot

in my project i have used achartengine for Scatter Charts but i am not able to click on point, so now i want use Scatter Charts of AndroidPlot, how can we implement that Scatter charts of AndroidPlot library ?

i have used below but i am not getting sample of Scatter Chart sample.
http://androidplot.com/
http://homepages.ius.edu/RWISMAN/C490/html/Android-Plot.htm

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A scatter chart is basically just an XY Chart where the points are not connected by lines.  AndroidPlot uses formatters to store information about how a series should be displayed.  In this case you'd use a LineAndPointFormatter that doesnt draw the line segments.  For example here's how you would instantiate one that only draws red dots:

```
// passing null as the line color disables lines    
LineAndPointFormatter lpf = new LineAndPointFormatter(null, Color.RED, null, null)
```